# Linguistic tools: what works best

Tags: semantics

I need to know what Linguistic tools are used when proving a bad translation has skewed the original message. I'm writing a paper trying to prove that the message found in present day bibles are very different from message written in Ancient Hebrew.

Comment: This is a very well-developed subfield. It sounds like you might be interested in textual criticism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textual_criticism

Comment: If you can think of the argument already, then you would have the tools you need. If you can't argue for your position, then how do you know you're right?

Comment: This seems to obvious to mention, but: backtranslation?